# What is the meaning of "on its side" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "on its side" in the following sentence,

> Uranus is the only planet to spin round ***on its side***.

?

Does "side" mean "axis" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A planet rotates on its axis. It also revolves around the Sun. For all the other planets, the axis is more or less perpendicular to the Sun, so the planet spins like a top as it goes around the Sun. If you could watch them from above, it would look like they were standing on their axes as they went around the Sun. Like a top. But with Uranus, the axis basically points toward the Sun. So if you could watch it from above, Uranus would look like it was rolling around the Sun.

If you don't understand, maybe I could figure out how to draw a picture to illustrate.

Comment: @ws2 Yes, that's why I said "more or less". This page, https://www.answers.com/astronomy/What_axis_tilts_do_the_planets_of_the_Solar_System_have, list the axial tilts of the planets. Note that most are 20 to 30 degrees. But Uranus is close to 90 degrees. So most planets' axes tilt somewhat, but Uranus is pointed almost straight at the Sun.

Comment: The axis of Uranus only points towards the Sun twice in each revolution (ie every 42 Earth years).

Comment: If so, does "Uranus is the only planet to spin round on its side" mean "Uranus is the only planet to spin round not standing up using its axis but standing up using its side"? Does "on" in the sentence mean "standing up using" mean?

Comment: @peter Yes, good point, I didn't say that right. I suppose the more accurate way to say it is that Uranus's axis is close to parallel to the plane in which it (and the other planets) revolve around the Sun. (And I don't have to say "the plane ... of the planets other than Pluto" any more because Pluto got kicked out of the planet club!)

Comment: @user175012 Basically, yes. I wouldn't word it quite that way, but I think you have the idea. Of course the planets do not "stand" on their axes like they are sitting on a big disc and need something to support themselves on, but speaking metaphorically, yes. And grammatically, I wouldn't say that Uranus "stands up using its side" but perhaps "stands on its side".

Answer (score 2):

[This video](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=2146666672277377) (courtesy of Jet Propulsion Laboratory, California Institute of Technology) explains the difference between the earth's rotation and that of Uranus.

The earths axis is not precisely perpendicular to its reviolution around the sun, but tilted at an angle of 23 degrees. Were that not the case we would not have seasons, and the length of the day would be exactly the same all year round - as it is on the equator.

Uranus's tilt is almost 90 degrees. **Hence it appears to be "spinning on its side"**

Answer (score 2):

Uranus is a planet and doesn't have a "side". So this sentence is a highly imprecise way of saying the planet's axis is tilted almost 90 degrees by (probably jokingly) comparing it with animals which can lie "on their sides".

This sentence makes as much sense as saying, "Humans adjust their axial tilt by 90 degrees for eight hours every night in bed", rather than saying, "Humans lie down."

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is likening planets to people, animals, or objects that are normally standing up vertically. When they rotate horizontally, as when you're lying on a bed, they're said to be "on their side" (or on their back or front, if they have distinct sides like this).

The solar system is mostly a flat plane, and the axis of rotation of most of the planets is veritical with reference to this plane -- they seem to be "standing up". But Uranus is tilted over, so it's described as being on its side.